# Or condition in find's regex expression

Tags: regex, linux, find

Why does it look up nothing when files are exist?

`find ./ -regex '.*(jar|war)'`

Comment: i am confused so you said find strings that begin with **.** followed by anything with war or jar attached to the end of the string?

Comment: In this particular case, `-name '*[jw]ar'` would suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See *man find* for information about supported syntax for regular expressions:

```
-regextype type
       Changes the regular expression syntax understood by  -regex  and
       -iregex tests which occur later on the command line.  Currently-
       implemented types are emacs (this is  the  default),  posix-awk,
       posix-basic, posix-egrep and posix-extended.
```

This works:

```
$ find . -regextype egrep -regex '(.*jar)|(.*war)'
```

To avoid using *-regextype* change the expression to an emacs regular expression:

```
$ find . -regex '.*\(jar\|war\)'
```

Comment: I added the emacs regular expression to the answer so you don't have to worry about the -regextype find argument.  Basically, in emacs expressions, one has to backslash escape parentheses and pipe characters.